# SpecRun execution results integration with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, specrun

Is there any possibility in SpecRun to include test execution results to TeamCity build information like it can be done for SpecFlow(see desired info on screenshot).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPjC4.jpg

For SpecFlow it's easy to get build information because of NUnit XML report is getting generated and TeamCity can parse it easily. But for SpecRun we don't have such a report.
I want to get such results as u can see on screenshot:

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you're asking if the test summary shows up on the build results summary, and populates the Tests tab. This may be what you're looking for:

```
SpecRun.exe BuildServerRun Default.srprofile /buildserver:teamcity
```

Source: https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-TeamCity/

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple!

1. get specrun.log text
2. split it by 'Total:'
3. get last part - it would be result of tests
4. pass it to TeamCity through `<TeamCitySetStatus Status="SUCCESS" Text="Total:$(YourResult)" />`

it will look like [this](http://gyazo.com/cf70061e5dddeb4d5c3921002aab5cb0).